# Best template engine for generate javascript from Node.js

Tags: node.js, code-generation, template-engine

For me, to produce HTML or XML, pug is favorite one.

However, when the expected result is not based on mark up language, I used to use Handlebars. But When I produce javascript dynamically using handlebar, It makes very difficulties to maintain templates and terrible readability to keep generated code pretty.

When I do same thing with java, I prefer to use Xtend.

Is there any template engine that is intended to generate code?
(which is not based on AST)

---

#### Full Scenario

1. I made a Java Script library using TypeScript.
2. To make Eclipse's Java Script type inference engine can support content assist for this library, I needed to create some TS to JS-skeleton trans-compiler. (result js just contains scheme and js-doc for Eclipse JS capability)
3. I used type-script from NPM to inspect library scheme.
4. I transformed TypeScript AST to my own purpose model to generate JavaScript files.
5. Then I need to generate Java Script files from this model, And I'm looking for best template engine.
6. The template engine should be easy to manage indent, iteration, conditional templates to generate clear code with readable template.

Comment: why do you want to generate JavaScript code dynamically? Can you give a use case?

Comment: you are not supposed to maintain the transpiled code

Comment: @MoritzMahringer I updated the question with full scenario.

Comment: I have found at least two popular libraries with a focus on templating JS: [hygen](https://github.com/jondot/hygen) and [doT](https://github.com/olado/doT).

Answer (score 0):

I am developer of [tsxt](https://github.com/iamguid/tsxt) it is strongly typed and based on JSX syntax with full typescript support, it is just babel plugin that transform your templates to string literals concatenation. Also i wrote an article about code generation https://medium.com/@iam.guid/first-typescript-jsx-based-template-engine-for-code-generation-d9be0275e6d6 check it for more information